# ReactJS : Is it possible to increment the TableHead - TableCell based on data from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Data looks in JSON as below

```
{
    "ModelName": "ObjectD",
    "ElementName": "573299",
    "ParameterInfos": [{
            "Name": "Bounding",
            "Value": "1"
        }, {
            "Name": "Dat",
            "Value": null
        }, {
            "Name": "Type",
            "Value": null
        }, {
            "Name": "Struct",
            "Value": "0"
        }, {
            "Name": "Base",
            "Value": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a new table in react using the column name from json as "Name", the data changes for each ModelName